# how to install google closure library with angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10, angular11, angular12, google-closure-library

I want to include the google closure library in my angular10 project. I'm installing using npm install google-closure-library but the following error given  **Could not find a declaration file for module 'google-closure-library'.**

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation properly and installed it [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-closure-library) library this is your library which you want to install.